# What does “you took long mate” means?

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning, american-english, conversation

In SMS messages:

> You took long mate
>
> Abit too much

What does “you took long mate” “abit too much” mean?

Answer (score 4):

It is colloquial and abbreviated, as text-speak often is.

I take it to mean "*you took a long time*", perhaps in replying to the original text message?

"Mate" just means "friend" and is common in UK and AUS English.

Although the statement "you took long" wouldn't be considered correct in spoken English, it *is* acceptable in the right context to say "*you took **too** long*". The sender of this message actually goes on to add "*a bit too much*", which they perhaps did to correct the first statement (although given the spelling and grammar in general, I doubt it).

Comment: @chialiong Reply with: **"What do you mean?"** and I suggest you do that anytime you don't understand something your friends say. This will help you learn English much more than asking us here for informal speech, and it helps teach your friends to be more clear and helpful when they use English with you. Have fun and just chat away!

Comment: **You took long** is perfectly viable in AmE.  It means that whatever you were doing or were up to was not over or finished or done quickly. It's often used by a speaker who has been waiting.   *Man, you took long!*

Comment: It looks like maybe Malaysian slang, from my experience.  You took long means "you took too long".  I'm more curious about what "You stitch" means in this context though.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes but Americans also say "*you did good*" instead of "*you did well*". They may say it, but it isn't correct.

Comment: @Astralbee:  "you did good" is regarded as substandard in AmE.

Comment: @david_c: When the image was larger it looked as though the embedded picture showed an embroidery hoop.

Comment: "You took long" doesn't sound particularly fluent to this American English speaker.  The use of *mate* is not all that common in American English either.